# route parameter doesn't work in mvc. why? how to fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013's new .net empty project with mvc and I have these...

**controller**:

```
public string Search()
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Search.");
}

public string Results(string query)
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Results." + "Query: " + query);
}
```

**routes**:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{query}"
    );
```

The issue is that the query parameter in

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{query}"
```

does not get mapped properly.

If I go to these two urls:

```
https://localhost:44300/Search/Results/?query=er
https://localhost:44300/Search/Results/er
```

only the first works.

For the first url the web page displays:

```
Results.Query: er
```

And the second one displays:

```
Results.Query:
```

I am following this example: [Adding a controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-controller) and cannot get the route to map the query parameter properly.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried a lot of things, such as renaming `query` to `q` to see if maybe the word query is reserved, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. fixed it.

the default route was wrong.

correct is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{query}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Search", query = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```